# When the object of std::function is destroyed?

Tags: c++, std-function

When the object of `std::function` is destroyed?
Why the pointer to the object of `std::function` is still valid when the variable `fn1` is out of the scope（you see the code snippet works well, [http://cpp.sh/6nnd4）](http://cpp.sh/6nnd4%EF%BC%89)?

```
// function example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <functional>   // std::function, std::negate

// a function:
int half(int x) {return x/2;}

int main () {
    std::function<int(int)> *pFun;
    
    {
        std::function<int(int)> fn1 = half;                    // function
     
         pFun= &fn1;   
         std::cout << "fn1(60): " << (*pFun)(60) << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "fn1(60): " << (*pFun)(90) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's still valid when it's gone out of scope?

Comment: It crashes in my windows. The address sanitizer throws `stack-use-after-scope`

Comment: @TedLyngmo You see the code snippet works well. http://cpp.sh/6nnd4

Comment: @John "works well" is one of the possible outcomes of undefined behavior. `*pFun` dereferences a pointer to an object that is no more ...

Comment: Just replace `std::function<int(int)>` with a simpler `int` and now ask yourself the same question. It's not like that a different type has a different lifetime.

Comment: @Jack2  Replacing `std::function<int(int)>` with a simpler `int`? How? `std::function<int()>`?  I didn't quite get your idea.

Comment: The idea is for you to grasp the concept of lifetime. The object has gone out of scope. Derefencing a pointer to it makes your program have undefined behavior - even if it appears to work. ... and no, @Jack meant a plain `int`, a pointer to it, and then dereferencing that pointer after the `int` has gone out of scope.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see. thank you. The key is lifetime of a variable. What confuses me is that the aforementioned code snippet works well when I posted such a question. Now I know that  "works well" is one of the possible outcomes of undefined behavior.Anybody can provide an online link which such code fails, I want to do more tests? All the compilers on https://godbolt.org/z/cr5e3o go well.

Comment: @Pablochaches Is there an online link on which such code fails, I want to do more tests. All the compilers on https://godbolt.org/z/cr5e3o go well.

Comment: @John Compile it with the address sanitizer. It will show you it fails. Still, I dont understand why you are doing so much testing on this. It is undefined behaviour, so it will work some times, but it is never guaranteed. [Here is your link](https://godbolt.org/z/fv1qvK)

Comment: Many people fight UB with the same thought. What makes UB even more confusing in C++ is that some compilers defines behavior (that goes above the C++ standard) for some situations. This is however not one I've heard about. This code has UB in all environments I've ever worked in. And do what @Pablochaches suggested. Use an address sanitizer - it's really revealing!

Comment: @Pablochaches Thank you for your patience and help. I fully understand it's an undefined behavior with your help now. I want to verify whether the object is destroyed or not after being pushed to `std::stl`(push object, not a pointer to the object).

Comment: @John I don't understand what "_being pushed to `std::stl` (push object, not a pointer to the object)_" means. You can have pointers all over the place. Just don't dereference those that points towards objects that are not "alive". Same-type objects may appear in the same space where the pointer points - and then it's ok to dereference again. Just keep track.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry, English is not my mother language. I may mislead you. See this simple code. It clearly shows what I meant. https://godbolt.org/z/seoo6E. Push the object of `std::function` to `std::stl`, not push the pointer of `std::function`. **The object is still alive beyond the scope (i.e variable `fn1`) by this method?**

Comment: @John Ah, I _think_ I understand where your confusion comes from in this case. No, the object is not alive beyond the scope. There is a _copy_ of the original object still alive in the map. `fn1` is dead - the object in `mp` is not.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see, thank you very much. I understand this matter at a different level with the help of you.

Comment: @John Cheers! Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the pointer to the object of std::function is still valid when the variable fn1 is out of the scope?

Let me present a simpler example, using ints. But if you are brave, you can try to read the assembler for the `std::function` version.

```cpp
int main () {
    int a = 0;
    int *c = nullptr;
    {
        int b = 1;
        c = &b;
    }
    a = *c;
    return a;
}
```

This is generated with gcc 10.2 -O0, but the other compilers have a really similar output. I will comment it to aid the understanding.

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0    # space for `a`
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], 0   # space for `c`
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], 1   # space for `b`
        lea     rax, [rbp-20]           # int *tmp = &b  Not really, but enough for us
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rax # c = tmp
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16] 
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]    # int tmp2 = *tmp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax  # a = tmp2
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]  
        pop     rbp                         
        ret                             # return a
```

And the program return `1`, as expected when you see the assembler. You can see, b was not "invalidated", because we did not roll the stack back, and we didnt change its value. This will be a case like the one you are in, were it works.

Now lets enable optimizations. Here is it compiled with `-O1`, the lowest level.

Here is it compiled with gcc:

```
main:
        mov     eax, 0
        ret
```

And here is it compiled with clang:

```
main:                                   # @main
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
```

And here is with visual studio:

```
main    PROC                                            ; COMDAT
        mov     eax, 1
        ret     0
main    ENDP
```

You can see the results are diferent. It is undefined behaviour, each implementation will do as it sees fit.

Now this is happening with some local variables in the same function. But consider this cases:

1. It was a pointer, lets say allocated with new. You already called delete. What guaranties that that memory is not used by someone else now?
2. When the stack grows, the value will eventually be overiden. Consider this code:

```
int* foo() {
    int a = 0;
    return &a;
}

void bar() {
    int b = 1;
}


int main () {
    int *ptr = foo();
    bar();
    int a = *ptr;
    return a;
}
```

It didnt return 1 or 0. It returned 139.

And here is [a good read on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope).

Comment: This is utterly pointless. The behavior is undefined. Full stop.

Comment: Yep, but it is to explain why it worked this time. At least I consider that interesting.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that C++ doesn't validate the contents of a pointer. That's the developer's responsibility. It only validates that the variable `pFun` is in scope.

In C++ it is often the developers responsibility to make sure that their pointers are pointing to valid objects. In this case, `fn1` has likely been created on the stack. Since many compilers implement local variables that way. When `fn1`goes out of scope the compiler will no longer allow the use of the variable `fn1`. However, what happens to the memory on the stack backing fn1 is not defined. In your case, the compiler left it untouched so `(*pFun)(90)` happens to still work. However, running the same code on another compiler may not. In fact, simply turning on compiler optimization may cause it to stop working. It all depends on whether the compiler re-uses that memory, or frees it from the stack.

In your example the scope is a code block. If the scope had instead been a separate function named `MyFunction2`then when `MyFunction2`exited the stack memory associated with `fn1` would have been freed off the stack and the memory available for reuse. Both by interrupts and whatever code was called after `MyFunction2`. So the data would be more likely to have been changed such that `(*pFun)(90)` faulted.

Now debugging something like this crashing is fairly strait forward. Imagine if you had written to `pFun` instead, this would have caused memory corruption of what ever object happened to be using that memory after `fn1` had gone out of scope.

Comment: Good Point Ted Lyngmo, I've updated my answer accordingly. Despite the question being closed.